# Using CASE statement with isnull and else

Tags: sql, t-sql, case

I have a column `Color` which contains `Black`, `Red`, `NULL`, `WW`, `RR`.

I want a column which has

```
if color black then 'B'
if color red then 'r'
if color is Null then 'Empty'
for all other entries 'n/a'
```

I'm using the following, but it throws an error:

```
SELECT Name,
        CASE color
            WHEN 'black' THEN 'b'
            WHEN 'red' THEN 'r'
            WHEN ISNULL(color, 'empty')
            else 'n/a'
           END AS Color_code
FROM SalesLT.Product;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use either `CASE` structure to do this, but you can't call a function if you use the `CASE fieldname WHEN` approach, so you can either use `CASE WHEN fieldname condition`:

```
SELECT Name,
        CASE WHEN color = 'black' THEN 'b'
            WHEN color = 'red' THEN 'r'
            WHEN color IS NULL THEN  'empty'
            else 'n/a'
           END AS Color_code
FROM SalesLT.Product;
```

OR:

```
SELECT Name,
        CASE color
            WHEN 'black' THEN 'b'
            WHEN 'red' THEN 'r'
            WHEN NULL THEN 'empty'
            else 'n/a'
           END AS Color_code
FROM SalesLT.Product;
```

Comment: Or create a function and just return the string, done! :)

Comment: @Zaggler You can't call a function on the column with the `CASE fieldname WHEN` version of `CASE` expressions.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. ISNULL statement is not working with when, but when you have else it works. As I'm a beginner, do not understand why.

Comment: @MyurathanKajendran You're saying neither query works? They work for me, could you describe what's not working?

Comment: Try this... `CASE color
  WHEN NULL THEN 'empty'
  WHEN 'black' THEN 'b'
  WHEN 'red' THEN 'r'  
  WHEN '' THEN 'n/a'
 END AS Color_code`

Comment: @HartCO your suggestion works perfectly. My question is why we could not use ISNULL function here? such as    
      when ISNULL(color, 'empty')
      ELSE 'n/a'

Comment: @MyurathanKajendran please see my comment on other answer.

Comment: The reason you can't use `ISNULL()` is because the `CASE` expression requires a `WHEN condition THEN result` structure. While `ISNULL()` is basically it's own little `CASE` expression.

Comment: Can I ask a common question here?. For one database I'm getting the Intellisense, but not for the other. What could be the reason?

Comment: I haven't encountered that, might be worth posting a question on: http://dba.stackexchange.com/ if you can't find an answer easily.

Answer (score 5):

You could try this way

```
  SELECT Name,
          CASE 
              WHEN color = 'black' THEN 'b'
              WHEN color = 'red' THEN 'r'
              WHEN color is null  THEN  'empty'
                ELSE 'n/a'
          END AS Color_code
  FROM SalesLT.Product;
```

Comment: It works like charm. Thank you so much. Can you answer me what is the reason for the second answer to be wrong. isnull() does not work with when .. thank you so much

Comment: @MyurathanKajendran the field type can't vary by row, thats why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

````
        CASE color
            WHEN 'black' THEN 'b'
            WHEN 'red' THEN 'r'
            else 'n/a'
            END* ISNULL(color, 'empty') AS Color_code
        FROM SalesLT.Product; ```
````

Comment: This question is asked more than 5 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer

Comment: I am new here. I didn´t know he had accepted an answer, I was just trying to help.